# How to create a histogram in charts.js with MYSQL data

Tags: html, mysql, database, graph, chart.js

I'm trying to create a histogram using charts.js and data from my database, but I cannot get it right. This is quite hard to achieve in my opinion as I want to display the amount of counts from my table between 2 numbers in the graph.

Can anyone help me?

In excel, the histogram graph is giving me this graph, which I exactly would like to achieve:

[image]

I have currently this code, which is giving me the histogram, but with manual entered data.

```
<canvas id="myChart" style="height: 450px"></canvas>
```

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [
            {x: 0.5,y: 100},
            {x: 1.5,y: 100},
            {x: 2.5,y: 200},
            {x: 3.5,y: 50},
            {x: 4.5,y: 50},
            {x: 5.5,y: 50},
            {x: 6.5,y: 50},
            {x: 7.5,y: 100},
            {x: 8.5,y: 200},
            {x: 9.5,y: 300},
            {x: 10.5,y: 400},
            {x: 11.5,y: 500},
            {x: 12.5,y: 600},
            {x: 13.5,y: 700},
            {x: 14.5,y: 700},
            {x: 15.5,y: 750},
            {x: 16.5,y: 500},
            {x: 17.5,y: 400},
            {x: 18.5,y: 800},
            {x: 19.5,y: 800},
            {x: 20.5,y: 800},
            {x: 21.5,y: 600},
            {x: 22.5,y: 300},
            {x: 23.5,y: 100},
        ],
            backgroundColor: [
                'orange'
                
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'grey'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
            barPercentage: 1,
            categoryPercentage: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'linear',
                offset: false,
                grid: {
                    offset: false
                },
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 3
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Hours'
                }
            },
            y: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Visitors'
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                callbacks: {
                    title: (items) => {
                        if (!items.length) {
                            return '';
                        }
                        const item = items[0];
                        const x = item.parsed.x;
                        const min = x - 0.5;
                        const max = x + 0.5;
                        return  `${min} - ${max}`;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then the array of data from my database is like this:

```
'0.1394777037264127','0.024053705901309844','0.099140010453889','0.0952842800859945','0.059904296397070074','0.11227852899574975','0.2694725273315774','0.1478234991270417','0.1027778408768443','0.06798357718974765','0.17120726752667134','0.09624120878208131','0.16482348905803088','0.1279912395396545','0.19090378523548093','0.09267433328059484','0.09992489347186286','0.026112911770833747','0.12495027602483877','0.0841193449607472','0.07170465816015695','0.11998962204728834','0.1010613498239313','0.027306167387460226','0.08641227568901573','0.15055431498562336','0.16781892895612258','0.1066867305185692','0.0875896152379209','0.19275123257158067','0.09855123659867356','0.0546127762654184','0.09557291981194872','0.11138107356961663','0.12179210409468506','0.06968579855193231','0.2272012955065279','0.04703647954993544','0.07659134497979021','0.10453218229631121','0.20953347485767995','0.048578849464321755','0.08699026736540491','0.07937820556276307','0.07629507665187894','0.08775694002598759','0.030730150422417366','0.1471336132151389','0.11197654856681181','0.06681399532169412','0.04452744486768262','0.05129371237884941','0.03431665813708926','0.057520964010649885','0.08438630666995003','0.0731803893903664','0.07125907389720447','0.1144677320278298','0.09576558980369032','0.14047525851370754','0.17839143571083838','0.1283099812617278','0.16402243083550277','0.02909351754684266','0.08681466964869233','0.08162036665948444','0.0757431329516536','0.08354122787875992','0.23522301726508016','0.05008224098796445','0.11046598625982963','0.17476634231452776','0.18477333826657705','0.06258718829042162','0.068412010013082','0.07063410884890124','0.16581019368819777','0.07828517956018827','0.06519951150302325','0.10649084647033422','0.15152887683737123','0.16689412599128983','0.039940801524151255','0.04272063805337432','0.03200172877717169','0.15039438437822836','0.06923227536421908','0.062129442817620256','0.11541823423294577','0.011239074157003743','0.09433731618594057','0.04483415963585437','0.03788259004264806','0.04410123217834868','0.03855244828340726','0.1637354796031739','0.06700550529507922','0.04736355886498697','0.07720181213103476','0.09599564647307038','0.05983865292025781','0.04514937227241766','0.09914732704579518','0.05135055429050793','0.1200788557839337','0.11077214678480783','0.3032529902441967','0.14011487807711687','0.08403659850708092','0.06821769694697873','0.1595312036816506','0.04799647075275914','0.0670902314984093','0.06892440794808406','0.17946062386165218','0.1468774805007055','0.12279435843807619','0.06671838252079278','0.0972539725772616','0.025910398922221713','0.05244651378593016','0.14014312465005185','0.1097690917494791','0.028796875802854196','0.11120219255995058','0.08371242531004074','0.15953652882241914','0.16067075087687804','0.10965694266241305','0.04612614408571251','0.07371016888275528','0.10845585329833812','0.12011656710595398','0.06605521039978357','0.09809406107011694','0.04176379194886088','0.027606934440116127','0.07064074744256887','0.09512601469718344','0.013057422640167586','0.1723834489814149','0.17297975695919396','0.03650877458359692','0.18348517712747622','0.12261329438629452','0.15516761445441152','0.13983925491692253','0.0741462107276753','0.0793920090626843','0.13102982808177036','0.10103643730164465','0.07440674691917164','0.12488949093636878','0.08636269832699858','0.15477239446748023','0.1927805798843565','0.45424762542580277','0.17555011940591334','0.07891445535264809','0.014563143147375803','0.07337658076001212','0.12772570793226695','0.009539194239137542','0.13459535863118968','0.09874027622220934','0.04601605242039647','0.06546298935995254','0.02787218862956835','0.06707914897362631','0.028070263623625604','0.04689469812574594','0.08834770610408564','0.0902207158817842','0.1465786801020027','0.06697378930195799','0.14813815571252398','0.1681796426505135','0.0684172317468488','0.16191311329793767','0.06955564189803619','0.061776111342443665','0.08270744073364233','0.08427465876380055','0.04713811655432392','0.10585064455053345','0.13797748782878405','0.04726232434463656','0.24210594935756322','0.07868520182479892','0.048619184035846204','0.042688324884247675','0.09334174690505706','0.2031418700298387','0.013852281456345431','0.06702357420976415','0.05063679547287109','0.09401580226096247','0.08239337922285851','0.04205387826455725','0.1242815986521689','0.1127724555768948','0.14576600992366956','0.09009778716682787','0.08199381237455625','0.2245170103607131','0.14278753239394665','0.18952962866083395','0.07617622010583902','0.129026181906681','0.18320224514376057','0.17617926479438767','0.18685020838644817','0.08896494886733303','0.08753108529574197','0.06571149834832818','0.04267904062981516','0.06985731332904224','0.08497446895764414','0.07278290236180257','0.12019609592448521','0.09770857313093188','0.12455015587187901','0.06476067954809321','0.14180787946175272','0.031511780519866694','0.0772660453437549','0.11761912773561554','0.08162545173624726','0.053889687174442945','0.3688429574484582','0.15252494007898867','0.08042757360510307','0.12431561001112537','0.05258710420383543','0.08249775867022797','0.08525270629220705','0.05351217388292697','0.006559777119564993','0.07344371728750912','0.18692967484908404','0.06377427297955861','0.1137161783968116','0.0429589525872786','0.09120913811338463','0.02214832470076398','0.030508884834720917','0.11107944028984541','0.12229205165204131','0.1426341692024242','0.07205842694561461','0.11649618019513669','0.041640818060699705','0.08100447543137967','0.04758814269378681','0.016163147057303866','0.05244335524946377','0.1883717557825402','0.14058870197266365','0.08730634357283015','0.13433750190772492','0.004331801220140042','0.2705961123563153','0.1989073072198614','0.08285474970786778','0.05216076351612366','0.12717998997019403','0.09608856322348222','0.08886271513977075','0.13389449704532336','0.11583977170032077','0.10821553433200376','0.14875742958993585','0.037125638478883706','0.09928326461365398','0.1234682661948654','0.12167342133342234','0.08350037440993764','0.05998985521056732','0.10013080192571577','0.10709856401337439','0.036289197673809635','0.0867557646105491','0.1123933025527617','0.1085427969969451','0.11868712556468926','0.02908045612823867','0.3247175695736471','0.06837420095507594','0.1410537006854','0.04600137108209353','0.038563210107898656','0.07628968808179812','0.08532835421368357','0.1240742429444043','0.2323210540866257','0.02860627842061206','0.06933074830279529','0.07464178570870496','0.047038666970459046','0.0943194509378416',
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fjk12rye/5/)

```js
const data = [
  {x: 0.5,y: 100},
  {x: 1.5,y: 100},
  {x: 2.5,y: 200},
  {x: 3.5,y: 50},
  {x: 4.5,y: 50},
  {x: 5.5,y: 50},
  {x: 6.5,y: 50},
  {x: 7.5,y: 100},
  {x: 8.5,y: 200},
  {x: 9.5,y: 300},
  {x: 10.5,y: 400},
  {x: 11.5,y: 500},
  {x: 12.5,y: 600},
  {x: 13.5,y: 700},
  {x: 14.5,y: 700},
  {x: 15.5,y: 750},
  {x: 16.5,y: 500},
  {x: 17.5,y: 400},
  {x: 18.5,y: 800},
  {x: 19.5,y: 800},
  {x: 20.5,y: 800},
  {x: 21.5,y: 600},
  {x: 22.5,y: 300},
  {x: 23.5,y: 100},
]
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var mixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: data.map(item => item.y),
    }],
    labels: data.map(item => item.x),
  },
});
```